# How to open iPhoto Library folder on a Mac

Tags: macos, iphoto

I remember that not long ago it was possible to open Finder and navigate to Pictures, then to iPhoto Library folder and then go inside the folder and open individual subfolders with jpgs in them.

It doesn't seem to be the case any longer - I see iPhoto Library of "iPhoto Library" kind (not "Folder") and opening it automatically opens iPhoto.

It presents a problem when trying to locate files, for example for attaching them to e-mail. E-mail programs simply see iPhoto Library as a package and not as a folder.

Please help me understand, is it a setting on my Mac, or a change in iPhoto? How do I locate picture files, other than searching through Finder?

I have iPhoto'09 version 8.1.2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike versions before iPhoto'08 iPhoto'09 uses package style libraries.

You can right click your "iPhoto Library" (in Finder, at least) and press "Show Package Contents" and it'll open up like a folder. The original pictures are in the folder named original and the edited (in iPhoto) pictures in the 'modified' folder. I'm not sure about the 'Data' folder (an alias to Data.noindex), it may just be a backup. To double check you can also right click on a picture in iPhoto and select 'Show File' and it will take you to the source location.

You can create aliases to the modified, data, and original folders to make access easier.

EMAILING STUFF:
When you have an "open file" dialog (to choose files to upload, etc.) on the left there is also a media section which makes it convenient to access iPhoto photos. Pretty easy actually, no need to navigate through a package.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked just as described. Screenshot - nice touch :)