# iPhoto Library: Remove its package-status?

Tags: macos, iphoto

[related to [this question]](https://superuser.com/questions/186385/how-to-open-iphoto-library-folder-on-a-mac)

I want to access this folder:

/Users/me/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Masters

but Picasa cannot find it because it's in a "package."

1. How can I make it not a package?
2. Will iPhoto still work? I'm guessing it will

Comment: "iPhoto Library" is a *folder with a file extension*. Open its *Get Info* dialog to find out its full name (e.g. `iPhoto Library.foo`). Then use that in Picasa.

Comment: @DanielBeck Picasa won't let me do it arbitrarily. Also, I'm not sure that's right? If I `cd` into the directory and do a `pwd` I see: `/Users/me/Pictures/iPhoto Library`

Comment: Odd, I only know packages with extension, that's how they're recognized. Are you sure you don't have both, i.e. `iPhoto Library` and some `iPhoto Library.foo`?

Comment: If Picasa uses the default OS X file dialog, you can press `Cmd-Shift-G` to navigate to on the UI unreachable locations.

Comment: @DanielBeck there's a bundle bit in OSX: http://i.imgur.com/UlQ9ahh.png. Thanks!

Comment: which doesn't help Picasa to see it, interestingly.

Comment: Thanks, learned something new today. `SetFile -a B someDir` makes `someDir` into a bundle (lowercase `b` reverts it). You should still be able to specify `~/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Masters` in the file dialog, assuming it's a directory.

Comment: nice, interesting stuff, I'll comment back when I solve this particular problem for Picasa